# JavaScript: alerting a specific value on my real-time database

Tags: javascript, firebase

I've been trying to achieve the following, but I couldn't

and here is my snapshot data:[image: screen]

If I wanted to alert **ada's** first name, what code should i use?

I used this, it returns undefined:

```
    if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
      alert('user signed')

      // Get a reference to the database service
var database = firebase.database();

      var query = firebase.database().ref("users");
query.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {


    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
      var key = childSnapshot.key.val;
      // childData will be the actual contents of the child
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();

        alert(key);
  });
```

but it didn't work, any suggestions?

error image:[image: sce]

> note: completely new to JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach), it is

```
// key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
var key = childSnapshot.key;
```

not `var key = childSnapshot.key.val;`

Comment: thanks this worked, this show's ada and alan randomly, but what if i wanted to get (ada)'s first name?

Comment: `childSnapshot.val()` gives you the object `{first: "rawand", last: "ahmed"}` that means `var childData = childSnapshot.val().first;` gives you the value for the `first` property.